# Prove the following metric space is complete

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I've been struggling with this question for many, hours.
Even reading the professor's proof outline, and understanding parts of it, I'm struggling with **completely** reproducing the proof on my own (pun *unintended*). His outline is in a different language, so I am translating and filling in all the technical details. My goal in this exchange is **proof verification**.

> Set $X= \lbrace (a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \mid \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
>  :a_n \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace $, the set of all infinite real sequences.
>
> Define a metric $D$ on $X$:
>
> $D((a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty},(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}) := \underset{n}{\sup} \lbrace\bar d(a_n,b_n)/n\rbrace$
>
> Where $\bar d(a,b):=\min \lbrace |a-b|,1\rbrace $,  for any $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> **Prove that $(X,D)$ is a complete metric space.**

I know that I need to show that every Cauchy sequence in $(X,D)$ converges in $(X,D)$.

So, given a Cauchy sequence, $\bar x_n = \lbrace x_n^i \rbrace _{i=1} 
^\infty$, I imagine setting up an infinite square matrix, where the $n^{th}$ column is the $n^{th}$ sequence in  $\bar x_n$ and the $i^{th}$ row is a sequence of all the $i^{th}$ elements in each sequence.

1. First, I want to show that every row sequence $\lbrace x_n^i \rbrace _{n=1}^\infty $, is Cauchy. I'm not sure if I did this correctly.

Let $i \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Since $\bar x_n$ is Cauchy, for every $\epsilon > 0$,  there exists   $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $m>n>N$:

$D(\bar x_n,\bar x_m)= \underset{i}{\sup} \lbrace\bar d(x_n^i , x_m^i)/i\rbrace = \underset{i}{\sup} \lbrace \min(|x_n^i-x_n^i|,1)/i\rbrace<\epsilon /i$.
It follows that  $\forall m>n>N: |x^i_n - x^i_m|/i<\epsilon /i$.
$\implies |x^i_n - x^i_m|<\epsilon$, proving that  $\lbrace x_n^i \rbrace _{n=1}^\infty $, is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$.
Since $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is complete, $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, \lbrace x_n^i \rbrace _{n=1}^\infty \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} L_i < \infty$.

$ $

2. Next, define $L= \lbrace L_i \rbrace _{i=1}^\infty$. Showing that $ \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim {\bar x_n}=L}$ completes the proof.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Set $K > \epsilon^{-1}.$ Since $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} : \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} x_n^i=L_i $, there exists $N$  such that $\forall n>N$:

$\forall 1\leq i \leq K  : |x_n^i-L_i| < i \epsilon \implies |x_n^i-L_i|/ i < \epsilon \implies \underset{ 1\leq i \leq K}{\sup} \lbrace \bar d(x_n^i , L_i)/i\rbrace < \epsilon$
$\forall i > K : i > \epsilon^{-1} \implies 1/i < \epsilon 
 \implies  \underset{i>K}{\sup} \lbrace \bar d(x_n^i , L_i)/i\rbrace < \epsilon$

Finally implying $D(\lbrace x_n^i \rbrace _{i=1}^\infty, \lbrace L_i \rbrace _{i=1}^\infty) < \epsilon \implies D(\bar x_n, L) < \epsilon$

Q.E.D
Wow, this took a very long time to write.
ANY feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Your proof is okay, just remember not to use $i$ as an index right after you have fixed it as in "Let $i\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary...".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline:

1. Let $\bigl(x(n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence of elements of your space. In particular, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $x(n)$ is a sequence $\bigl(x(n)_k\bigr)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of real numbers.
2. For each $k\in\mathbb N$, prove that the sequence $\bigl(x(n)_k\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers. Let $x_k$ be its limit.
3. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x(n)=(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Great. I have the same setup as you outlined. I imagine the Cauchy sequence as an infinite matrix. Every column is an infinite series. In step 2 I need to prove every row in itself is a Cauchy sequence. This results in every row converging to xk. The “last” column composed of these limits is the limit sequence in my space. I was hoping for more details on steps 2 and 3 since these are the challenging steps. Maybe if you could explain what D and d intuitively mean, I could do it on my own.

Comment: The distance $\overline d(a,b)$ is the usual distance if the numbers $a$ and $b$ are close to each other and $1$ otherwise. As far as limits (or being a Cauchy sequence) are concerned, this is the same thing as the usual didtane, but it cann never be greater than $1$. And the distance $D$ between two sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is small if and only if the distance between the first terms of both sequences is small.

Comment: Would the question be very different if d was defined to always be 1?

Comment: @ikoikoia It sure would. For instance, neither $\overline d$ nor $D$ would be metrics.

Comment: How about the other way around? Why is the 1 necessary?

Comment: Otherwise, the $\sup$ that you have in the defiinition of $D$ might well not exist.